# loop to set UIImages from document directory on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have 9 buttons whose images are set by the user dynamically. Each button's current image is saved the user documents folder. In `viewDidLoad` id like to re-set each image to it's UIButton.

I can do this easily enough with:

```
NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName: @"boss1.png"];
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *savedBoss = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
[boss1Button setImage:savedBoss forState:UIControlStateNormal];


...... 8 more times....
```

Of course Id prefer to do it using a loop. Only, Im not sure what that would look like in objective C. In jQuery I could do something like:

```
$('.bosses').each(function( index ) {
    var imageUrl='../images/boss'+(index+1)
    $('#'+this.id).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')')
});
```

How can I create a similar `objective-C` loop that would increment the boss image name and button name similarly?

Furthermore, is there a better way to do this entirely?

I feel like maybe having an `NSArray` of image urls and an NSArray of `UIButton` names and pairing them together using a loop might be better.... but again I'm not sure what the syntax would look like for that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be like:

```
    //Add all the buttons in an array for easy loop
    NSArray *array = @[btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4... etc];
   NSString *name = @"BOSS";
   int x = 1;

    for(UIButton *btn in array){ // loop through all the buttons

        NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",name,x]];
        NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        UIImage *savedBoss = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
        [btn setImage:savedBoss forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        x++;

    }
```

Comment: perfect, had to change the case of "boss" but but was exactly what I needed and very readable, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try like this and have button tag like 1 to 8

```
for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
  if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)subview;
    NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFromate@"boss%d.png", button.tag]];
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImage *savedBoss = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
    [button setImage:savedBoss forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```

This will do.

Comment: Working on it now, `isKindaOfClass` should be `isKindOfClass` I think, right?

Comment: This will work assuming you already have added the buttons in the view.

Comment: Im impressed you got it that close without autocomplete! Looks like `stringWithFormat` is a little off, fixed it (I think) but still throwing "Expected ']' ` NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat@"boss%d.png", button.tag]];`

Comment: Yes @Joshua and if he need to add button you have already show him a way :)

Comment: @Joshua yep they are set up in the storyboard